# I tried to write a program that loops the question until the user types stop but I keep on getting the invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to make it loop the question until the user types stop, but I get invalid syntax error.

Code:

```
while True:
  inp = input("Enter a Number: ")
  if inp == "Stop":
    break

num = int

if num > 1:
      for zzz in range(2,num):
        if (num % zzz) == 0:
          print(num,"is not a prime number")
          print(zzz,"times",num//zzz,"is",num)
          break

else:
  print(num,"is a prime number")
else:
  print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Comment: What is line 33? I can't count that high.

Comment: Look at the traceback you're getting (the text that leads up to the `SyntaxError`. Python even usually displays a little `^` indicating where it can no longer process the code.

Comment: `num = int` won't cause that error, but that's surely wrong. Did you mean `num = inp`?

Comment: (Hint: indentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your syntax error and fixes the code;

```
while True:
  inp = input("Enter a Number: ")
  if inp == "Stop":
    break

  num = int(inp)

  if num > 1:
        for zzz in range(1,num):
          if (num % zzz) == 0:
            print(num,"is not a prime number")
            print(zzz,"times",num//zzz,"is",num,'\n')
            break

          else:
              print(num,"is a prime number")
  else:
      print(num,"is not a prime number")


print("")
print("By Ronan Stanford")
```

Comment: How do I get it to loop the entire thing and not just the `inp = input("Enter a Number: ")`

Comment: @RonanStanford modified the code, just needed to indent all the code with the loop

Comment: Thanks mate! I have not looked at this in a long time, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score -2):

Python is very particular about indentation. You need to line up each `else` with its matching `if`.

Comment: You could show him where it's obvious he is a beginner

Comment: @RonanStanford I'm not sure why you are getting down votes. Your question is mostly clear. I can tell you are a beginner, but I'm also more than willing to help where I can. Be sure to answer any comments in order to clarify what you are asking about.

Comment: @Dharman Congratulations! You have been selected for A/B testing